# How to reference the input of a step function in my glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I have a simple step function that takes an input at the start . I want to pass the input to my glue job which does some processing on the input and writes the output to a file in S3. Here is the script for that :

Step function code :

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "Glue StartJobRun",
  "States": {
    "Glue StartJobRun": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "Job1",
        "Arguments": {
          "input.$": "$.input"
        }
      },
      "End": true,
      "Credentials": {
        "RoleArn": "xxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code for the glue job :

```
import sys
import json
import boto3

from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

# Initialize the GlueContext
sparkContext = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sparkContext)

# Get the input from the output of Job1
input_value = sys.argv[1]

# Append "ed" to the input
output_value = input_value + "passed"


# Write the result to an S3 file in a dedicated folder for this job
job_folder = "Job1"  # Replace with the job name
# Replace with your S3 bucket and file path
bucket_name = "xxx"
output_key = "Job1/output.txt"

# Initialize the S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Upload the result to S3
s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=output_key, Body=output_value)
```

But the input that i take in my glue job seems to be a boolean true and false and not the real value of string being passed. How do i take the in put of the step function in my glue job.